# JQuery - force multiple ajax requests to run in sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sequence

The following executes each ajax call using jQuery in sequence.  The calls must be in sequence.  The only way I've found this works is by using async: false, which I know is deprecated and should not be used.  The code below loops through each element in the [name] array and fires each ajax request in sequence.  When I remove async: false, the ajax calls are made out of sequence and sometimes one of them does not seem to fire at all.  I thought ajaxComplete might help me here but I've had no luck.  Is there a way to make these ajax calls fire in sequence?

```
function doGetJson(name1) { 
    var URL = 'http://some url/?name=' + name1;
    $.ajax({
        url : URL,
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        async: false,
        jsonpCallback : 'getJson',
        name: name1,
        index: i,
        success : handleJson
    });
};

function handleJson(data) {
    <...some other operations...>

};

var name = "test1,test2,test3".split(",");

for (var i = 0; i < name.length ; i++ )
{
    doGetJson(name[i]);
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need to make the ajax calls in-order?

Comment: The result of each ajax call is a map layer, which has to be added to the map in a certain order.

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of promises. First let your function return the `$.ajax` like so:

```
function doGetJson(name1) { 
    var URL = 'http://some url/?name=' + name1;

    // notice the return !!!
    return $.ajax({
        url : URL,
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        async: false,
        jsonpCallback : 'getJson',
        name: name1,
        index: i,
        success : handleJson
    });
};
```

Then you chain them like that:

```
var name = "test1,test2,test3".split(",");

var promise = name.slice(1)
    .reduce( (a,b) => a.then(doGetJson.bind(null, b))
       , doGetJson(name[0]) )

promise.then(function(){
    // do something when all requests are ready
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I seemed to have solved this by replacing any reference to the call back getJson with a unique callback name.  Instead of getJson I used "name 1".  I think jQuery reuses the call back function which might cause issues with sequential asynchronous calls.